# Laravel - Getting string from a flash

Tags: laravel-4

After processing form input, I redirect to a new route with some flash data:

```
return Redirect::route('work.index')
       ->with('flash', 'New work entry has been entered');
```

In the controller specified by `work.index`, I try to access the data

```
$flashed = Session:get('flash');
```

However, instead of a string, I end up with an array with two sub-arrays, `old` and `new`

Am I doing something wrong? Am I supposed to do this?

```
$flashed = Session::get('flash')['new'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Store Data for next request

```
Session::flash('city', 'New work entry has been entered');
```

Retrieve Data from last request

```
$data = Session::get('city');
return Redirect::route('work.index')
   ->with('data', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Advice is to use Laracasts/Flash package that helps you to manage Flash messages in an easy way.

Here the GitHub repo: https://github.com/laracasts/flash

### Installation

First, pull in the package through Composer.

```
"require": {
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.0"
}
```

And then, if using Laravel, include the service provider within `app/config/app.php`.

```
'providers' => [
    'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider'
];
```

And, for convenience, add a facade alias to this same file at the bottom:

```
'aliases' => [
    'Flash' => 'Laracasts\Flash\Flash'
];
```

And you can use it with:

- `Flash::info('Message')`
- `Flash::success('Message')`
- `Flash::error('Message')`
- `Flash::warning('Message')`
- `Flash::overlay('Modal Message', 'Modal Title')`

Now in your theme you can easly integrate it with:

```
@include('flash::message')
```

NB:
Note that this package is optimized for use with Twitter Bootstrap.